# How can I tell if this iPhone supports Game Center challenges?

Tags: ios, game-center

Game Center challenges were only made available in iOS 6, but Game Center itself was available much earlier (iOS 5?).

If I want to show a Challenges button in my game, it needs to be hidden when played on older devices. Is it ok to just test the version string to be > 6, or is there a more reliable way?

Comment: Have you checked this Doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW5

Comment: @BuntyMadan: I'm not looking for game center, I have already solved that problem. I'm looking for challenges within game center, which aren't available on all versions of iOS that have game center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply testing for the existence of `GKChallenge` worked for me:

```
bool gameCenterAreChallengesAvailable()
{
    return NSClassFromString(@"GKChallenge"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this test to see whether the relevant method exists:

```
if ([GKAchievement instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(issueChallengeToPlayers:message:)])
{
    // Challenges exist on this device, show button.
}
```